# Azure Data Factory data flow expression unexpectedly scrambled

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an usual derive Columns activity in my ADF data flow, which is simply concatenation of some fields and should be error-free.

The expression in expression builder:
[image]

First unexpected behaviour I observed is that, there is no data preview available in the expression builder (while other fields in same derive column activity have):
[image]
When I press the "Save and finish" button, the display in the Derived Column's settings show error in the expression:
[image]
I tried to investigate and reopen the expression builder, the expression is unexpectedly scrambled:
[image]

Is there any explanation for the behaviour? And do we have some fix / workaround for me to keep the original expression?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **curl** brackets in the expression to include the columns.

```
toString({ContactType@ID}) + '_' + toString({ContactType@Name}) + '_' + toString({ContactType@ModifiedDate})
```

[image]

You can also use the **CONCAT** function to combine multiple string values to get a value.

```
concat(toString({ContactType@ID}) , '_' , toString({ContactType@Name}) , '_' , toString({ContactType@ModifiedDate}))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The 2 workarounds are working for me. May I know if there is any explanation for the strange behaviour? I guess it is the @ sign messing up things? As I observed that the situation only happens when the expression contains the @ sign.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it might be because of @ in the column name. I have noticed, if the column name contains any special characters like @ or space in between, it should be enclosed in brackets when used. I have looked up for explanation but did not find any related documents.

Comment: One thing I find that is mildly interesting from `concat` 's explanation: *Concatenates a variable number of strings together. Same as the + operator with strings*.. Nevetheless, thanks @NiharkaMoola-MT for the satisfactory explanation.